# SQL Placeholders/Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a date column (I'm new and learning) that is a VARCHAR structure and I was inserting into the column using mm/dd/yyyy.

Later realised this wasn't proper and to use the DATE structure and YYYY-MM-DD

Instead of purging my table I want to be able to convert my mm/dd/yyy's into a suitable YYYY-MM-DD so I can then change the column structure to DATE

My first step was to replace all the /'s with -'s so I tried:

`REPLACE ("__/__/__", "/", "-");`

But obviously got unexpected token errors. How can I go about achieving what I want to do?

Comment: `UPDATE table SET new_date = STR_TO_DATE(str_date,'%d/%m/%Y')`

Comment: First test it by doing a `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(str_date,'%d/%m/%Y')` to make sure it does the date conversion correctly